# Get rid of space when printing a new line using standard output in c++ and ncurses

Tags: c++, output, space, ncurses

Hello I'd like to know how to get rid of the space created 
when printing a new line in c++ using ncurses library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    initscr();
    noecho();

    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    cout << "World" << endl;

    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

I have this output
Hello
----World

(The dashes are the space I mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offhand, I'd expect this output:

```
Hello
     World
```

since curses puts the screen into raw mode, suppressing the cooked-mode feature that converts output line-feeds into carriage-return/line-feed.  If you really want to print

```
Hello
World
```

you should use curses calls (which also happen to work *with* curses output *buffering*):

```
addstr("Hello\n");
addstr("World\n");
```

Besides the misformatted output, mixing `cout` with curses can cause your output to be sent in a different order than the curses calls.  That's what I meant by *buffering*.